# How to delete a zip/jar file automatically after extraction

Tags: ant

After extracting a zip or jar file,is there a way to delete the source zip/jar file automatically in ant

Answer (score 3):

Not that I know of, but you should be able to use the delete task:

```
<unzip src="thefile.zip" dest="somedir"/>
<delete file="thefile.zip"/>
```